# How to access js variable (within script tag) in ejs view as ejs variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a script in order to get the selected option of a select tag in my ejs view, this is in order to dynamically set the value of the name attribute to the selected option. I then use the name of this input tag in my nodeJS server-side. However, I receive `ReferenceError: p is not defined`.

What is the correct way to access the JS variable in my ejs view?

EJS

```
<select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>

<!-- JS as a tag in the EJS !-->
<script>
let p = document.querySelector('select').selectedOptions[0].value;
</script>

<input type="file" name="<%= p %>">
```

Any help much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is your <script> tag among the <body> tag?

Comment: ejs is not reactive, so p is not defined. p is set after render not during or before

Comment: @JoseVasquez my script tag is in within the body tag

Comment: @LawrenceCherone If so, how should I go about setting the name attribute with the value of the p variable?

Comment: EJS variables are evaluated on the server, the client's browser evaluates the JS variables *long* after the server has already generated the page and sent it on. You need to do what you're trying to do either purely inside EJS or purely with JS in the browser.

Comment: As @LawrenceCherone said, EJS is not reactive, that means your Javascript won't re-render the HTML tree. [Here](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.ui.practices/html/web/w3c/html_priority_w.htm) you can find the priorities when it comes to render HTML. Alternatively you can define your <input> with an id like <input id="identifier" type="file"> then right below your javascript code define this line **document.getElementById('identifier').setAttribute("name", p)**.

Comment: You are storing you variable whose type is let You know the scope of let variable is in the block in your case inside the script tag. Thats way in the below code it has no scope. Try var instead of let. Hope it may help you.

Comment: @Basit It doesn't help. See previous comments.

Comment: I see @GuyIncognito. I know ejs variable evaluated on the server but i say we can try

Comment: You can also try throwing salt over your shoulder and reciting Ave Maria, but the result will be exactly the same.

Comment: @JoseVasquez Thank you, that helps. And if the user changes their selection, the attribute won't change again, in order for it to change again, would I have to add an event listener on the select tag to run the setAttribute code again, or is there a more efficient way of doing that? Thanks once more.

Comment: Yes, add a listener on the select tag. Since you are not using a reactive Framework like ReactJS or VueJS. Otherwise take a look into one of those frameworks and you can try to add one to your project. I strongly recommend you to use a reactive framework for better performance when it comes to larger/scalable projects.

Answer (score 1):

EJS code is executed on the the server and JS code is executed on the browser.

The only way to have EJS access your DOM variable is if there was a call to the backend API  via JS code and then have that evaluated and returned to frontend, but this is a poor design and is not recommended.

Its better you handle the the value of  tag via JS only, the details will be sent to sever on form submission.

Comment: ejs is not server side only, its simply a templating language

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes, that is correct :) My assumption here was he is using ejs as a view engine in his nodejs backend code.

Comment: @Sai Do you have a URL you can point me to that states what you said? Thanks for your answer